# How to clone branch from specific AWS Code commit account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

We had 4 individual AWS accounts for Dev,QA, UAT and Prod.

I need to clone a repository from AWS Prod account with branch name Production.

The problem is I am using the command

```
git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/vanguard"
```

which is working fine, but I am not sure the cloned repository belongs to which AWS account since I am not providing any AWS account details while cloning the repository to my local.

The clone URL

```
https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/vanguard"
```

is same in all AWS accounts.

How to clone a repository from specific AWS Code commit account only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create an `IAM` role in that AWS account you want to clone the repository from. The `IAM` role will delegate access to that repository to IAM user/users in the AWS account.

Then, you would have to configure your `AWS CLI` to use AWS Security Token Service (STS) and assume the role when running commands.

Also, note that, each `CodeCommit` repository is associated with an AWS Region.

Here's more on [assuming roles with AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html).

EDIT:

Here's what's need to be done to enable **Cross-Account Access** to a repository in a different account:

**Repository Account Actions:**

1. Create a policy for access to the repository.
2. Attach this policy to a role in the same account, and allow users in the user account to assume this role.

**User Account Actions:**

1. Create an `IAM` user or `IAM` group. Use these to access the repository from the other account.
2. Assign a policy to the user or group that allows them to assume the role created in the repository account as part of the previous step.

Finally, assume the cross-account role *before* you attempt to clone or otherwise access the repository. Also, make the necessary changes to your credentials file `~/.aws/config`

For example:

```
[profile MyCrossAccountProfile]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyCrossAccountProfile
source_profile = user1
```

Lastly, you need to modify the `AWS CLI` credential helper so that you use `MyCrossAccountProfile`

```
git config --global credential.helper `!aws codecommit credential-helper --profile MyCrossAccountProfile $@'
```